# JS Design Pattern for setting a var set for functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react project but I think this question relates to all JS

I have a Token file that contains the following functions:

```
export default {
      set(token) {
        Cookies.set(key, token);
        return localStorage.setItem(key, token);
      },
      clear() {
        Cookies.remove(key);
        return localStorage.removeItem(key);
      },
      get() {
        try {
          const retVal = localStorage.getItem(key) || '';
          return retVal;
        } catch (e) {
          return '';
        }
      },
```

Now I want to add a set of what are essentially environment variables for the domain of these 3 functions. In my case its based on window.location.hostname but could really be anything.

In this instance lets say we want key to be dev, uat or prod based on window.location.hostname

```
getKey = host => {
 if(host === 'a')
  return 'dev'
 elseIf (host === 'b')
  return 'uat'
 else
return 'prod'
}
```

I think the above is fairly standard to return the key you want. but what if your key has 6 vars, or 8, or 20. How could you set all the vars so that when you call set(), clear() and get() that they have access to them?

Basically I want to wrap the export in a function that sets some vars?

To illustrate this a bit more

```
class session extends Repo {
  static state = {
    current: false,
  };

  current(bool) {
    this.state.current = bool;
    return this;
  }

  query(values) {
      <Sequelize Query>
    });
  }

export session = new Session();
```

using this I can call current(true).session() and sessions state would be set to true. I want to apply a similar pattern to the Token file but I don't want to change all my calls from Token.set(token) to Token.env(hostname).set(token)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite follow what the question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: `Basically I want to wrap the export in a function that sets some vars?` like a class?

Comment: _but what if your key has 6 vars, or 8, or 20._ I guess you mean _values_, not _vars_. Just return an array of values

Comment: No I don't want an array of values, I want to access variables with the names. preferably with this.foo 
Jim I added a class we use but I will admit that I don't fully understand beyond the scope we use.

Comment: You should be able to define `hostname` in Token's constructor, if you are using a class, when instantiating a new instance, no?

Answer (score 0):

This acomplished what I wanted, I had to call the function from within the others as window is not available on load. It essentially illustrates the pattern I was looking for. Thanks for Jim Jeffries for pointing me towards the answer.

```
class Token {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      testKey: null,
    };
  }

  setCred = host => {
    if (host === 'uat') {
      this.state.testKey = 'uat';
    } else if (host === 'prod') {
      this.state.testKey = 'prod';
    } else {
      this.state.testKey = 'dev';
    }
  };
  set(token) {
    this.setCred(window.location.hostname);
    Cookies.set(testKey, token);
    return localStorage.setItem(testKey, token);
  }
  clear() {
    this.setCred(window.location.hostname);
    Cookies.remove(testKey);
    return localStorage.removeItem(testKey);
  }
  get() {
    this.setCred(window.location.hostname);
    try {
      const retVal = localStorage.getItem(key) || '';
      return retVal;
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
export default new Token();
```

If anyone else has another idea please share.